# In-place migration from WCF-based Rest API to WebAPI

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Basically, we have an old API that is written as a WCF Rest API which consists of multiple (20 or so) services. We would like to migrate to a WebAPI based solution, however "simply starting over" is not a viable option for many reasons.

So, long story short: Is there some way to replace my old WCF Rest API on a service by service basis with a WebAPI implementation, basically running the two in parallel while migrating bits over?

Specifically, one of the most interesting issues could be making sure the WCF and WebAPI context is synced (as we currently use an extension on OperationContext.Current), so that means we would have to resolve the ContextProvider depending on service used I guess?

Well, if anyone has any inputs I'd be very happy :)

Comment: `OperationContext.Current` is a WCF concept (as well as anything on `System.ServiceModel`), you won't be able to use that in Web API. If the WCF service runs on OWIN/IIS, you should be able to create a new Web API project and copy over all the services and start migrating from there (this should be easier than adding the Web API stuff into the WCF service)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes, I am aware of that ... which is why I said this might be a pain point that needs addressing (the actual context we use is WCF-independent, just how it is shared per request is not -> this could be addressed by refactoring in some way)

Answer (score 1):

You could create your Web Api services as facades that call your existing WCF services. That way you can start coding clients to your new services while maintaining any legacy code that called your old services. Obviously this entails the overhead of the additional service calls, you could incrementally replace the code behind the facades with your new business logic, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda my last resort but undesirable for multiple reasons. A method of running them in parallel would be a much better migration path for everyone involved I think (but I'll keep this one in mind)